# Custom bullet list is not displaying well

Tags: css, html-lists

I am trying to create custom bullet listing but it doesn't display well to what I expected.

The problem is it is too close as shown in the link HERE
[image]

Suggestion will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: This is a question about CSS. We would need to know the CSS and the markup for the list. The tag's aren't correct. It has nothing to do with Wordpress.

Comment: You can set a `lineheight` or add `padding` or `margin` to fix this problem.

Comment: Some code would help providing a better answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can play with :after and :before selectors.
My suggestion it would be to go with something like this:

```
ul{list-style:none;}
li{padding-left:15px; position:relative;}
li:before{content:" "; position:absolute; left:0; height:10px; width:10px; background:url(path/img);}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably try to specify a `line-height` for the `<li>`'s.

Like:

```
<ul class="custom-list">
    <li>some item</li>
    <li>some other item</li>
</ul>
```

And the css:

```
.custom-list li {
    line-height: 20px;
}
```

Check jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/excentris/ycANw/) change the `line-height` and click run to see the effect...

You might also need to tweak the position of your custom bullet images, but as I said on my comment, you should provide some code example or better yet a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) to be able to help you any further...